# Wordpress WP_Query without query GET parameters

Tags: php, plugin-development, wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, mysql

I have filter plugin on page. And I get generated SQL query by shortcode presets and query string params.

So I want to get SQL query without affecting by query string GET params.

For example. I have page url where I have a filter.

### 1 example

> https : //example.com/snapbacks/

So if I have url like this. WP_Query generates this SQL query

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1  AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (38) AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (
            SELECT object_id
            FROM wp_term_relationships
            WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (341)
        )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 
'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 16
```

### 2 example

If I have url page like this

> https : //example.com/snapbacks/?pa_brand=nike

I have this sql query

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = tt1.object_id) WHERE 1=1  AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (46) AND tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (38)  AND  wp_posts.ID NOT IN (
            SELECT object_id
            FROM wp_term_relationships
            WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (341)
        )) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 16
```

So I have a several questions.

1. How to get sql query showed in first example on page https : //example.com/snapbacks/?pa_brand=nike where "?pa_brand=nike" part added.
2. How WP_Query generates SQL query? From url or $_GET/$_REQUEST arrays?

Answer (score 1):

The transition from URL to SQL in WP is quite long and elaborate.

In a very nutshell:

- URL gets rewritten into a GET request
- GET request gets converted into query variables
- query variables are used to instance main query
- main query generates SQL

There are a *lot* of nuances to this process, hooks that fire during it, and logic within. This essentially *is* WordPress, the very core of its core.

Also note that `WP_Query` might easily generate *more than one* SQL query, both for logical and performance reasons.

If I follow your question right you have some extension customizing query with its own GET argument. Simply put there is no way to just "tell" WordPress to give you a "clean" query in this case. You would need to study what exact customization is being done and how it should be handled for your purposes, without breaking function it performs.